# Exporting Html Table to Excel with styles

Tags: javascript, html, excel, html-table, export

I am trying to export a little bit complicated html table to .xls format. I found plenty of guides about it, already tried tableExport, DataTable Buttons plugin, some pure Javascript solutions but all of them just gave me an Excel table without any style, colspan or rowspan attribute. My html table is like that. Is there any other solution that works properly for this situation?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
 
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <title></title>
 <meta name="generator" content="LibreOffice 5.4.3.2 (Linux)"/>
 <meta name="created" content="2017-09-12T11:45:45"/>
 <meta name="changed" content="2017-11-24T14:27:12"/>
 <meta name="AppVersion" content="14.0300"/>
 <meta name="DocSecurity" content="0"/>
 <meta name="HyperlinksChanged" content="false"/>
 <meta name="LinksUpToDate" content="false"/>
 <meta name="ScaleCrop" content="false"/>
 <meta name="ShareDoc" content="false"/>
 
 <style type="text/css">
  body,div,table,thead,tbody,tfoot,tr,th,td,p { font-family:"Arial"; font-size:x-small }
  a.comment-indicator:hover + comment { background:#ffd; position:absolute; display:block; border:1px solid black; padding:0.5em;  } 
  a.comment-indicator { background:red; display:inline-block; border:1px solid black; width:0.5em; height:0.5em;  } 
  comment { display:none;  } 
 </style>
 
</head>

<body>
<table cellspacing="0" border="0">
 <colgroup width="302"></colgroup>
 <colgroup span="8" width="113"></colgroup>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=9 rowspan=2 height="110" align="center" valign=middle bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><b><font size=6>WEB PROJE KIMLIGI</font></b></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=9 height="55" align="center" valign=middle bgcolor="#FFFF99"><b><font size=4>PROJE BILGILERI</font></b></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="55" align="left" valign=middle><b>PROJENIN SAHIBI</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=8 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="55" align="left" valign=middle><b>PROJENIN ADI</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=8 align="center" valign=middle>td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="55" align="left" valign=middle><b>PROJE URL</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=8 align="center" valign=middle><font color="#0000FF"></font></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="55" align="left" valign=middle><b>PROJE YETKILISI</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="55" align="left" valign=middle><b>PROJE TEKNOLOJISI</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=8 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=9 height="55" align="center" valign=middle bgcolor="#FF3399"><b>NETWORK ve GUVENLIK BILGILERI</b></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="55" align="left" valign=middle><b>ERISIM SAGLANICAK NETWORKLER</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=3 align="center" valign=middle><b>INTERNET</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=3 align="center" valign=middle><b>IC NETWORK</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="55" align="left" valign=middle><b>ERISIM YASAKLI URL ya da KLASORLER</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><b>INTERNET</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><b>IC NETWORK</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="55" align="left" valign=middle><b>SSL KULLANIMI</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=3 align="center" valign=middle><b>VAR</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=3 align="center" valign=middle><b>YOK</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="55" align="left" valign=middle><b>SSL FORCE EDILECEK PATH LER</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=9 height="55" align="center" valign=middle bgcolor="#66FFFF"><b>PROJE KAPASITE BILGILERI</b></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="55" align="left" valign=middle><b>PROJE BOYUTU</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><b>MB</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><b>GB</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="55" align="left" valign=middle><b>ACILIS SAYFASI BOYUTU</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><b>MEVCUT / DUSUNULEN</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><b>SENELIK ONGORULEN</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="55" align="left" valign=middle><b>BIR SENELIK GENLESME ONGORUSU</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><b>MB</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><b>GB</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="55" align="left" valign=middle><b>KLASOR YAZMA IZINLERI</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="55" align="left" valign=middle><b>AYLIK ZIYARETCI</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><b>MEVCUT / DUSUNULEN</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><b> SENELIK ONGORULEN</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=2 align="center" valign=middle><br></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=9 height="55" align="center" valign=middle bgcolor="#FFCC00"><b>VERI TABANI BILGILERI</b></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" height="55" align="left" valign=middle><b>KULLANACAGI VERI TABANI TEKNOLOJISI</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=4 align="center" valign=middle bgcolor="#FFFF99"><b>SQL</b></td>
  <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" colspan=4 align="center" valign=middle><b>ORACLE</b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- ************************************************************************** -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Export to Excel from where?  Javascript?  Could you show the code you've tried so far?  Also check out the [tour] as well as [mcve].  Welcome!

Comment: From Html? The question is simply clear to understand. I want to get this html table as .xls file, that means i want to export it to excel while downloading. I tried maybe 10 plugins about this problem. Can't paste all of them, it will look like garbage.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place where you ask other to work for you. Show the result of your reserch, what you tryed, etc. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) to know how ask good question. And you really have no idea of what you need to do, maybe start by [learning programming](https://www.codecademy.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple other important links: the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) further to the comments above.

There are many plugins available for free that work just fine for copying html tables with formatting (I use Tabletools2 for Firefox), but if you're having trouble with them, a VBA solution is not for you.  (If you still require a custom built solution, coders are available for hire.)

If all else fails, **the method below (no plugin required) worked *perfectly* for me on **your table** and took me under 5 seconds; give it a shot.

[image: html to excel]

Good luck.